# Leapfrogging with natural joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following setup:

[image: three tables with commonalities].

What I'd like to do is extract the names from Table C belonging to category 1 in Table A (i.e., what I've highlighted), and I need to do this using Natural Joins only.

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
SELECT First, Last FROM TableC NATURAL JOIN TableB, TableA WHERE TableA.Category=1
```

It gives me all the first and last names associated with Tables A and B.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It helps to be a bit more specific than "doesn't work". It's also better to put tables and data etc. in the question as text rather than images.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole, by "doesn't work" I meant I get the wrong result (not an error). It gives me all the first and last names associated with Tables A and B. Re: text over images; I didn't know how to explain myself in words so I found it easier to draw a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing ANSI and old-style joins, which is a bad idea, and you're ending up with no join condition between two of the tables. You're creating a natural join between C and B, but then have a cross join (but in old syntax) between the result of that and A. If it works at all and doesn't give a shntax error, it will give the wrong results.

Use ANSI joins consistently; you need to specify that both are natural joins:

```
SELECT First, Last
FROM TableA
NATURAL JOIN TableB
NATURAL JOIN TableC
WHERE TableA.Category=1
```

With your data set-up:

```
create table tablea (category number, pin number);
insert into tablea values(1, 101);
insert into tablea values(2, 102);
insert into tablea values(1, 103);
insert into tablea values(3, 104);
insert into tablea values(1, 105);
insert into tablea values(3, 106);

create table tableb (pin number, login number);
insert into tableb values(101, 201);
insert into tableb values(102, 202);
insert into tableb values(103, 203);
insert into tableb values(104, 204);
insert into tableb values(105, 205);
insert into tableb values(106, 206);

create table tablec (login number, first varchar2(20), last varchar2(20));
insert into tablec values(201, 'Joe', 'English');
insert into tablec values(202, 'Alan', 'Smith');
insert into tablec values(203, 'Lucy', 'Parker');
insert into tablec values(204, 'Brad', 'Finch');
insert into tablec values(205, 'Kate', 'Young');
insert into tablec values(206, 'Rachel', 'Turville');
```

This gets the result you wanted:

```
SELECT First, Last
FROM TableA
NATURAL JOIN TableB
NATURAL JOIN TableC
WHERE TableA.Category=1;

FIRST                LAST
-------------------- --------------------
Joe                  English
Lucy                 Parker
Kate                 Young
```

Comment: Thanks again @AlexPoole, unfortunately this still doesn't solve my problem. I still get the wrong result (not an error)

Comment: @Granada - yes it does. I've created your data from your images (which would have been much easier with text, or if you'd given those statements), and it gets your highlghted names. What are you doing differently?

Comment: Don't you mean: SELECT First, Last; FROM TableC; NATURAL JOIN TableA; NATURAL JOIN TableB; WHERE TableA.Category=1?

Comment: All those superfluous semicolons are syntactically incorrect. Go back and check the data in each of your tables - it appears that the data is not what you think it is. Best of luck.

Comment: I just re-created the tables and ran Alex's query and (not surprisingly) it returns the corect output. What result do you get, Granada? OK, not an error message - but what is the incorrect result you get?

Comment: @Granada - it doesn't matter, it's logically the same and gets the same three-row resultset (without the exta semicolons, which would cause errors so I guess you aren't really doing that). Oracle's optimiser will choose the best order to actually do the joins. I prefer having the filtered table first as it makes more sense to me, but it makes no difference here.

Comment: And just to beat this particular horse to death, I [created an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/963a0/1) (using PostgreSQL because SQLFiddle's Oracle support has been broken for some time now, but no matter), ran Alex's query, and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input, I'm learning a lot. The problem is that I get all the names in the table, and not just the ones corresponding to category 1. However, I replaced `First, Last` with `*`, and the output First Last columns are correct. So now my question is, how do I just show those two columns?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Are you running exactly what I showed and tested, and what Bob put in his Fiddle? Which shows you what you wanted, three rows, rwo columns. Using `*` will show the same three rows but with the pin and login columns too; it changes the columns, not the rows or filters.

Comment: I agree @AlexPoole it doesn't make sense. I'm so confused and frustrated. I think I'll need to think about it a bit longer on my own. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: UPDATE: It appears the database I was working with was in some way corrupted, producing many rows when I specified the columns I wanted, and only the required number of rows when I used an asterisk. Therefore @AlexPoole's answer was helpful, so I marked it as accepted. Thanks everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to perform using other join. Check this might give u required result:

```
 SELECT First, Last FROM TableA JOIN TableB on (TableA.Category=1 and TableA.Pin=TableB.Pin) JOIN TableC on TableB.Login=TableC.Login
```

Comment: The question says "I need to do this using Natural Joins only".

Comment: oops dint notice that @AlexPoole